opentelemetry Spring boot starter is not injecting spanId and traceId to MDC
So I am trying to configure my spring boot app to use OpenTelemetry Spring boot starter. I'm using logback for logging, and I'm using application.yml for application configuration.
When calling the app endpoint, I am not seeing spanId and traceId present in the MDC.
I have followed the instructions and here's everything I've done so far:
Added otel configuration into application.yml
otel:
  exporter:
    otlp:
      endpoint: <exporter url>
      compression: gzip
  service:
    name: <service name>
    instance:
      id:

Added dependencies into build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '3.2.6'
        junitJupiterVersion = '5.9.2'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'idea'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'com.github.jk1.dependency-license-report' version '2.5'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-instrumentation-bom:2.8.0")
    }
}

ext['jackson.version'] = '2.16.1'

group 'com.test'
version '1.0'
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter:2.8.0'
    implementation 'io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-logback-mdc-1.0:2.8.0-alpha'

    //spring
    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:4.2.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:3.2.6'

    // SNAKEYAML
    implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0'

    // kotlin stdlib
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.20'

    // open feign
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:4.1.2'

    //dev utils
    api("org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.10.0")
    api("com.opencsv:opencsv:5.7.0")
    api("jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.2")
    api("commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0")


    //move to lib
    api group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version: '3.8.3'

    //test
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8-standalone:2.35.1')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner:4.1.2')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy(jacocoTestReport)
}

tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required = true
    }
}

Added traceId and spanId to logback-spring.xml appender
<appender name="stdoutotel" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <pattern>
                    %date{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] [%X{AppName}] [%X{AppVersion}] [%X{actionId}] [%X{userId}] [%X{workspaceId}] %logger{35} : %msg trace_id=%X{trace_id} span_id=%X{span_id} trace_flags=%X{trace_flags} %n
                </pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

Added a dummy endpoint
@RestController
public class TestHttpAdapter {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void isImportInProgress(
    ) {
        //Custom logger
        logInfo(action(ACTION_NAME)
            .message("Dummy log message")
            .build());

        //Checked if the MDC contains spanId and traceId (It doesn't)
        MDC.getCopyOfContextMap().forEach((key,value) -> {
            System.out.println(key + "  " + value);
        });

        //Checked if spanId even exists (It does exist and it prints normal trace id to console) 
        System.out.println(Span.current().getSpanContext().getTraceId());
    }
}

My expectation is that the log I made will have spanId and traceId in it, but that's not the case. I also expected that MDC would get populated with spanId and traceId, but that's not the case either.
It's also important to note that currently we are using opentelemetry-javaagent, and since we want to utilize CRaC, javaagent is preventing CRaC to create a checkpoint, and that's the reason why we want to get rid of javaagent. I've also opened the issue on javaagent repository some time ago.
Additional note is that I'm not keen on implementing manual instrumentation either, because there would be a lot of code written, and I leave this as the last resort.
Ideally, we could configure the spring-boot-starter (and/or opentelemetry java SDK) to do the same job javaagent did, without any code changes . I hope that is possible somehow but right now I'm not getting anywhere because the basic example of adding opentelemetry spring-boot-starter doesn't work as I'd expect.

I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a solution? Thanks in advance.
